# split page 50/50%, regardless of further content

Tags: html, css

Consider the following page layout:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
</div>
```

which is styled like this:

```
html, body { margin: 0px ; height: 100%; }

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#a { height: 50%; }
#b { height: 50%; }
```

Assuming that `#a` and `#b` don't get additional `padding` or `margin` style-attributes, is there a chance that any additional content inside those divs could cause the 50/50 split to break? Or make the container exceed the 100% percentage rule and causing the page to have scrollbar.

I'm using this as atop level page layout and I want to make sure that the 50/50 split is always respected, regardless of any further additional content within the #a and #b divs.

https://jsfiddle.net/4v9ag66n/

Comment: Add some content and see: https://jsfiddle.net/4v9ag66n/1/

Comment: [I am sure this will help you.](https://css-tricks.com/left-and-right/)

Comment: No, not without script ... well, yes, if `#a` will always have more content, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4v9ag66n/3/

Answer (score 1):

To be sure you can add `overflow-y: hidden;` to the #a,#b divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add overflow-y:scroll or overflow-y:hidden to #a and #b in that way both div will have separate scroll bar/ noscroll bar if content are more but page will have no scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

I think this css (your css that I modified) should achieve what you're after:

```
html, body { 
  margin: 0px ; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#a { height: 50%; overflow: auto;}
#b { height: 50%; overflow: auto;}
```

Also, you might want to look at the word wrap.